# how can I get the percentage of each value according to the column

Tags: r

I am trying to get the percentage of each value in a column. I tried different ways but I cannot figure out how to do that.

This is an example data

```
df<-structure(list(process = structure(1:16, .Label = c("A", "AA", 
"AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA", "B", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "BBBBB", "BBBBBB", 
"C", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC", "CCCCC"), class = "factor"), num = c(60L, 
79L, 114L, 72L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 20L, 19L, 10L, 84L, 4L, 9L, 27L, 
5L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

here is what I do

FIRST METHOD

library( dplyr )

```
df %>% 
  group_by( num) %>% 
  summarise( percent = 100 * n() / nrow(df))
```

Method 2

```
df %>% mutate(df, percentageNUM =num/sum(num)
```

So here is the process to calculate the percentage 
1- I should take the sum 
then get the value percentage based on that sum

for example for the first value which is 60, it will only be 11.215% OF THAT DATA

SO THE OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THESE VALUES

```
num     
60      11.21495327
79      14.76635514
114     21.30841121
72      13.45794393
6       1.121495327
14      2.61682243
2       0.373831776
20      3.738317757
19      3.551401869
10      1.869158879
84      15.70093458
4       0.747663551
9       1.682242991
27      5.046728972
5       0.934579439
10      1.869158879
```

Comment: And what should be the output? Can you please post it?

Comment: Do you need a grouping by 'process'? i.e. `df %>% group_by(grp = substr(process, 1, 1)) %>% summarise(percent = 100 * n()/nrow(.))` or `df %>% group_by(grp = substr(process, 1, 1)) %>% mutate(percent = num/sum(num))`

Comment: @d.b I think your answer gives me the result !!!!!

Comment: your method2, just needs `100*`.  also, `df %>% mutate(df,` is incorrect `df %>%  mutate(percentage = 100 * num/sum(num))`